# How can we run queries concurrently, using go routines?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I am using gorm v1 (ORM), go version 1.14
**DB** connection is created at the start of my app
and that **DB** is being passed throughout the app.

I have a complex & long functionality.
Let's say I have 10 sets of queries to run and the order doesn't matter.
So, what I did was

```
go queryset1(DB)
go queryset2(DB)
...
go queryset10(DB)

// here I have a wait, maybe via channel or WaitGroup.
```

Inside queryset1:

```
 func queryset1(db *gorm.DB, /*wg or errChannel*/){
      db.Count() // basic count query
      wg.Done() or errChannel <- nil
    }
```

Now, the problem is I encounter the ***error :1040 "too many connections"*** - Mysql.
Why is this happening? Does every go routine create a new connection?
If so, is there a way to check this & "live connections" in mysql
(Not the show status variables like connection)

How can I concurrently query the DB?

Edit:
[This guy has the same problem](http://teejayvanslyke.com/beware-of-making-database-queries-in-goroutines.html)

Comment: Should share ```queryset1()``` code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not directly related to `go-gorm`, but to the underlying MySQL configuration and your initial connection configuration. In your code, you can manage the following parameters during your initial connection to the database.

- maximum open connections (**SetMaxOpenConns** function)
- maximum idle connections (**SetMaxIdleConns** function)
- maximum timeout for idle connections (**SetConnMaxLifetime** function)

For more details, check the [official docs](https://go.dev/doc/database/manage-connections) or [this article](https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/configuring-sqldb) how to get the maximum performance from your connection configuration.

If you want to prevent a situation where each goroutine uses a separate connection, you can do something like this:

```
// restrict goroutines to be executed 5 at a time
connCh := make(chan bool, 5)

go queryset1(DB, &wg, connCh)
go queryset2(DB, &wg, connCh)
...
go queryset10(DB, &wg, connCh)

wg.Wait()
close(connCh)
```

Inside your queryset functions:

```
func queryset1(db *gorm.DB, wg *sync.WaitGroup, connCh chan bool){
    connCh <- true  
    db.Count() // basic count query
    <-connCh  
    wg.Done() 
}
```

The `connCh` will allow the first 5 goroutines to write in it and block the execution of the rest of the goroutines until one of the first 5 goroutines takes the value from the `connCh` channel. This will prevent the situations where each goroutine will start it's own connection. Some of the connections should be reused, but that also depends on the initial connection configuration.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer.
So, every go routine will create a new DB connection?
Is there some way to monitor live connections?

Comment: Not necessarily. Connections are taken from a pool of connections. If a connection can be reused, it will be, so some goroutines might reuse an existing connection, and some might create new connections.
As for monitoring, you can use the `DB.Stats()` function to get some information. Check this for more info: https://orangematter.solarwinds.com/2018/05/22/new-stats-exposed-in-gos-database-sql-package/